# Get this error with tabs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, tabs

My JS knowledge is quite close to null. I am working on a website and I made some custom tabs. I need the first one to be open by default. Yesterday I added this script to my JS code ( I am working in wordpress by the way) and it worked fine!

`<script>
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>`

Yesterday it was working but today I didn't move a thing and no matter what I do it won't work again. In the console I get this error:

Get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Any ideas what could this be? Why was it working in the past and not now? I tried open in a different browser or to clear the cache but it keeps happening and I am curious on why it worked before and not now and how can I fix this. Does anyone have any suggestions please? I'm a JS noob.

EDIT: None of the past questions these peopel asked solved my problem. So it is not a duplicate.